# Dropbox: API permission by folder?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to only request access to one folder? Dev guide (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide) talks about permissions by file type but doesn't mention permissions by folder. Dropbox allows sharing of folders through their UI is there application permission setting to get access to a folder through their API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't currently offer a custom path-based permission. We're tracking this as a feature request though.

Comment: Any news on path-based API permission?

Comment: No, no news on this.

Comment: Any news on path-based API permission?

Comment: No, unfortunately no news on this.